# Phonegap Android app reset to main screen each time while orientation change

Tags: android, cordova, android-manifest

I am creating the phonegap application for android platform but when i change the orientation it will reset and going back to the main screen each time.

```
<application android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|keyboard|locale" >
    ...
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
    ... 
</application>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add android:configChanges under activity tag not in application tag 
like :-

```
<application >
...
    <activity
       android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|keyboard|locale" 
       android:name="com.example.myapp.MainActivity"
       android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
... 
</application>
```