# Screen orientation not working in android eclipse build

Tags: android, eclipse, jquery-mobile, cordova, screen-orientation

I have developed a jquery mobile + phonegap app. The app screen orientation works perfectly fine when I make apk from build.phonegap.com. Now I have make an android project in eclipse, imported cordova, every thing is working fine but not screen orientation. The below function does not fire up, as screen is not adjusted properly. When I rotate the screen, control is taken to home screen of the app.

Here is the code:

```
window.onresize=function(){
    // I adjust screen here
};

var _orientation=null;

$(window).bind('orientationchange', _orientationHandler);
function _orientationHandler(event){
   if(event.orientation){
        _orientation=event.orientation; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Aren't you using an old version of phonegap?

Comment: I used same phonegap.js and cordova.js that is plaved by build.phonegap.com. But after making apk from eclipse, problem arises.

Comment: phonegap is not just js files, and actually when you install phonegap in the recommended way, you don't copy phonegap.js or cordova.js, they're copied automatically by the CLI. The issue you encounter was common with phonegap 2.x (don't know when exactly it was corrected) and we had to solve the issue by patching the main class java gile. No more issue with phonegap 3.x

Comment: i use last build of cordova
it can't be problem

Comment: I have found the issue, actually android restarts the app at screen orientation

Comment: actually it restarts the activity not the app and it is handled with phonegap 3.x so you should not have the problem

Comment: It's handled automatically with new project in phonegap3, but you can try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590600/phonegap-android-app-reset-to-main-screen-each-time-while-orientation-change